# Is ordinal multiplication commutative?

Tags: set-theory, arithmetic, ordinals

> DISCLAIMER I am sure this is a duplicate yet I coudn’t find an answer I was looking for so I’m probably going to ask and then eventually flag it as a duplicate.

Is every instance of ordinal multiplication commutative?

More specifically: if we had $\alpha^2\cdot\alpha^\beta$, where both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are transfinite ordinals, does this give $\alpha^{\beta+2}$ or $\alpha^{2+\beta}$ which is just $\alpha^\beta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinal multiplication, like ordinal addition, is noncommutative.

$$2\omega=\omega\lt\omega+\omega=\omega2$$

$$\alpha^{\beta+\gamma}=\alpha^\beta\alpha^\gamma$$

$$\omega^2\omega^\omega=\omega^{2+\omega}=\omega^\omega\lt\omega^{\omega+2}=\omega^\omega\omega^2$$

Comment: To the proposer: For ordinals $x,y,$ think of $xy$ as $y$ consecutive copies of $x.$  E.g. $2\omega =\omega $ because a list of $\omega$ consecutive copies of $\{0,1\} $ is order-isomorphic to $ \omega.$  In fact we can define $xy$ as the ordinal that is order-isomorphic to the lexicographic ordering of $y\times x.$